# GDB assembly cannot toggle JNS jump

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb

I am debugging an application with GDB. 
There is a comparaison of strings and then a jump (JNS):

```
   0x8048410 <main+32>: call   0x8058a70
   0x8048415 <main+37>: add    esp,0x10
   0x8048418 <main+40>: test   eax,eax
   0x804841a <main+42>: jns    0x8048436 <main+70>
```

The state of the stack after the test instruction is the following:

```
EFLAGS: 0x286 (carry PARITY adjust zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
```

Capital letters mean the flags are activated.
GDB Peda says the jump is NOT taken since the SIGN flag is activated, at least that's how I understand the JNS instruction, jump on NO SIGN.

I would like to follow the jump instruction so I toggled the flag off:

```
set $SF = 7
set $eflags &= ~(1 << $SF)
```

you can see the SIGN flag is disabled:

```
EFLAGS: 0x206 (carry PARITY adjust zero sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
```

but gdp peda still says that the jump is NOT taken, and when I actually try to step, it doesn't take the jump.
Is the problem in my understanding of the JNS instruction or am I missing something else?

EDIT: Not sure why but the jump does work after changing the flag, but peda does not understand the change and still says that the jump won't be taken. I will check this a bit more before writing an answer.

Comment: Your understanding of `jns` is correct.  The NS condition is true when `SF=0`, and false when `SF=1`.  You're sure your method of setting flags is correct, and that you're doing it after the `test` but before the `jns`?  If you use `layout reg`, you can watch the state of regs (including EFLAGS) change as you single-step.  (see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)

Comment: Is it possible you are looking at EFLAGS before `test eax, eax` is executed rather than after? If you were doing that then whatever you were setting the flags to would be clobbered by the test and the JNS would take whatever path it normally would.

Comment: I'm venturing to guess from the output that the original source code looked something like `if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 1, 0) < 0)`

Comment: Alternatively you can just set `EIP` to the target of the branch, see the `jump` command.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah I used peda but layout reg basically shows the same results, SF flag disappearing after I toggled it. But for some reason it actually jumped at the right place. It just seems that peda misinterprets the fact that the jump is taken or not. So not sure why it didn't work but I am sure that peda is wrong about the jump.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Why would you think this is the original source code? the check with "< 0" I understand but the rest?

Comment: @Jester yes this is what I ended up using to get through this but I still wanted to understand why I could not make it work.

Comment: Did you try using just plain `gdb`?  I don't know anything about Peda except for one second with google, but maybe there's a bug in it?

Comment: @user3714670 : Although you said "debugging an application", the contents of the question smelled more like a challenge. The fact that you program is in function `main` likely suggests not a real world program. Using the debugger to set the flags intentionally was a clue that you were likely doing some code cracking. PEDA is a big hint. I happened on a lark to take `call   0x8058a70` and not much to my surprise I landed at [this website](https://osandamalith.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/solving-root-me-ptrace-challenge/) with *nearly* identical debug output although the comparison was different

Comment: One can say I used "duck typing" to come to my conclusion (before google searching). What walks like a duck, what quacks like a duck, is usually a duck ;-). Stackoverflow is a favorite destination for crack me challenges, binary bombs etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Good thing I had completed the challenge before checking the site, I wouldn't have resisted otherwise. Yes it is the same, thanks for your answer.